# Hangouts as chatrooms

Tags: chat

I was hoping I could use Hangouts as chat-rooms, but it doesn't seem that easy.

What I was expecting is that I can bring my Hangout contacts into a chat-room authorized by their hangout ID.  Also all members should have access to all the history of the chat-room.

Is this possible?  Is it possible with some other tools?

Need authorization by GMail or similar, and good support on different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for group chat functionality, then yes, Hangouts has it.

First, pick one of the contacts in your group that you want to add to the chat.
[image: pic1]

Then, you'll see the chat box pop up. Click the little icon of a person with a plus sign to add more people to the room.

[image: pic1]

Keep adding people as needed.